# standard error of regression coefficient without using inverse

Tags: linear-regression

I want to compute the standard error of regression coefficients:

```
y = X$$\theta$$ + e
```

where theta is the regression coefficient.  I know the formula is:

```
$$V(\theta) = \sigma^2 (X^T X)^-1$$
```

How can I calculate the above formula without computing the inverse?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the answer is to use residual bootstrap.